# React Native Redux Navigation initial state param

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

https://snack.expo.io/HJKoZNuv-

I want to go straight into the `DayStack.Day` screen with `AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Day', { day: '1' })` but the `{ day: '1'}` param is not getting passed to the navigator at

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: `Day ${navigation.state.params.day}`,
}),
```

`navigation.state` is undefined.